# Compilation error: method render in class list cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm still learning Play!Framework and, as a lesson, I decided to include a new feature in a application (available in Samples, called "Computer Database").

Well this app is very simple. It has a Computer model and it has a `@ManyToOne` relationship with a Company model. Well, basically I decided to copy Computer model and I made a Employee model, which is basically the same. I copied Computer Model, Controller and Routes and I tried to compile unsuccessfully, as you can see below:

```
public static Result list(int page, String sortBy, String order, String filter) {
    return ok(
        list.render( //-- LINE IN RED!
            Employee.page(page, 10, sortBy, order, filter),
            sortBy, order, filter
        )
    );
}
```

Actually, I tried to compile it because I was looking for more tips, as I have other issues in my Eclipse, only in my new Controller, called "Employees". The code above is marked with:

```
Multiple markers at this line: Occurrence of 'render'; The method render(Page<Computer>, String, String, String) in the type list is not applicable for the arguments (Page<Employee>, String, String, String)
```

And only in this controller I have static methods Result update/create/save/delete pointed with a message:

`The method render(Form < Computer >) in the type createForm is not applicable for the arguments (Form < Employee >)`

The point is: I'm not trying to use this method with Employee obj arguments. Every single method contains: `Form< Employee > employeeForm = form(Employee.class)...`

My IDE is saying this method render is not applicable for the Employee Page's arguments, only for Computer Page's, which sounds totally weird for me, because, as I said, it is a generic class, a play-framework native class, and Employee and Computer are models created by me.

--

- Employee.page's signature:

  `public static Page< Employee > page(int page, int pageSize, String sortBy, String order, String filter)`

--

I searched a dependency/library inconsistency, but personally I could find it. I've already tried to restart Eclipse, my server, "play clean"/"update"/etc in the console... What else could I verify?

Comment: What is the signature of `list.render` that you *are* trying to use, and what is the signature of `Employee.page`? There's a lot of information we don't have here...

Comment: Please edit the information into the *question*.

Comment: As per my previous comment - please put this in your *question*... although we only need the *signature* of `page`, but also the signature of `render`...

Comment: Employee.page and list.render included! Thank you

Comment: No, you've included a *call* to `render` (which looks like the same call you showed earlier on), but you haven't included the *signature* of `render`. Additionally your post is now pretty hard to read. I suggest you edit it...

Comment: According my IDE, this *render* in *list.render* is from `Referenced Libraries/classes_managed/views.html/list.class`. Did I include what you are looking for about *list.render*?

Comment: No, you haven't included it at all. I want to see the signature of the method you're trying to call: its return type and parameters. It looks like it might be `render(Page<Computer>, String, String, String)` but it's hard to see because you've been using `<code>` in your post instead of Stack Overflow's built-in code formatting... And we don't know the type of `list`, or how `render` is declared in code... if `list` is a generic type, that's almost certainly relevant.

Comment: `list` is a totally play-framework's generic class. It is in one of referenced libraries. And `render` is a method from this generic class. 

The question my IDE is saying this method render is not applicable for the Employee Page's arguments, only for Computer Page's, which sounds totally weird for me, because, as I said, it is a generic class, a play-framework native class, and Employee and Computer are models created by me :/

Comment: I suspect (well, hope) that `list` itself isn't a class. It's certainly not named in a conventional manner. I expect it's a variable, and we don't know its type. Find the declaration of `list`, and edit that into your question. It's *really* hard to help you with this very slow dripfeed of information. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list and http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved my issue. We simply replace the code like `list.render` for a previously ready code called `listEmployees.render` and then we did the same for `public static Result save` and `public static Result create`, and in this case, for its corresponding `createEmployeeForm`, which was also previously done. But we were not using the Employees' views originally developed for this, because our great Eclipse IDE was pointing issues.

We simply ignored this Eclipse issue and, voilà, it runs! Then we refreshed the project and now it's right. Thanks for all attention!