# Play Framework compiling causes "method render in class views cannot be applied to given types" error

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I am new to the Play Framework and am passing values from a controller to a view.  When I compile in activator (in the Command line), I receive this error:

```
[error] C:\WebDev\git\PlayAuthenticate\app\controllers\Application.java:633: met
hod render in class views.html.profile.profile cannot be applied to given types;
[error]   required: play.data.Form<controllers.Application.ProfileRegister>,java
.util.List<models.Service>
[error]   found: play.data.Form<controllers.Application.ProfileRegister>
[error]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
[error] profile.render
```

Here is my function in the controller:

```
public Result addProfile() {
    List<Service> services = Service.find.all();
    return ok(profile.render(form(ProfileRegister.class), services));
}
```

Here is the first line in the view.html.profile.profile:

```
@(profileForm: Form[Application.ProfileRegister], servicesList: java.util.List[Service])
```

I am not sure what I am missing.  When I remove the second parameter -- the List object -- it compiles.

I found a few posts, but it did not fix my problem:

[Play Framework 2.2.1 - Compilation error: "method render in class index cannot be applied to given types;"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993442/play-framework-2-2-1-compilation-error-method-render-in-class-index-cannot-b)

[Compilation error: method render in class list cannot be applied to given types;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292519/compilation-error-method-render-in-class-list-cannot-be-applied-to-given-types)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Eclipse did not like the space between the parameters.  I removed the space and the project compiled.